# PHP error is driving me nuts

Tags: php, mysql

so I get the error below

**[25-May-2013 06:15:43] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/eightcoz/public_html/doyourbit/match.php on line 6**

... and match.php contents: I have ommited the "< & >"

```
**?php
include("settings.php");
$random = rand(0,99999999);
$ekle = mysql_query("INSERT INTO likebutton(data) values('$random')");
$show = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likebutton");
$total=mysql_num_rows($show);
echo "= ".$total;
? likes**
```

.. the database is called **eightcoz_charity_likes** & contains a table called **likebutton**

Comment: From the docs" _For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error._ There's your answer. Btw, check the warning, `mysql_*` shouldn't be used anymore...

Comment: Try adding `or die(mysql_error());` to your mysql functions: connection establishment, queries, etc.

Comment: What's with the `**?php` and `? likes**`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all mysql*_ is depriciated.
secondly, its for a charity site, you must use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  to prevent injections 
thirdly, you get the warning because mysql failed to make sense of your query 
you might want to use [this](https://www.php.net/mysql_error) to find what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **count** like

```
$show = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM likebutton");
$total = $show['total'];
```

and try to use mysqli_* functions because mysql_* functions are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Something might be wrong on the database connection configuration. It would be clear what went wrong if you had posted the settings.php